# How to split 1 big question (and answer) into several questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I know that answering our own questions is encouraged. I had a problem and found a solution. The thing is, it is a rather big problem (and solution). So I'm thinking about splitting it into several questions.

1. Is it OK to do this?
2. What is the best practice to "link" these questions since they are closely related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be technically okay to do this, but the questions really do need to stand alone, independent of one another. If they're so closely related that you can't figure out a way to break them up into separate questions, then they should be asked as a single question.

The upper limit for posts is something like 30,000 characters, and I've only seen one guy who hit up against this. I don't really think it's a problem in practice, so if it's easier to ask it all in one question, then I'd say go ahead and do that.

Of course, if the questions are just *related*, but not actually dependent upon one another, you could always just include a link at the bottom to the other question. Something like:

> **Related:** [Link to My Other Question]

or

> **Also see:** [Link to My Other Question]

I would also advise you to think about the answers the question would receive, as if you were *not* going to self-answer. There's nothing wrong with self-answering, of course, but there's also nothing wrong with another user coming along later and providing a different answer to a question you've already self-answered. In fact, that's kind of by-design—they might have an even better solution to share.

If what you're asking can be answered in a single, cohesive answer, then it works as a single question. Otherwise, the questions need to be broken up.