# How to reasonably split questions up?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I asked this question: [No notification of reputation loss; Questions deleted - how can I check what I did wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147273/no-notification-of-reputation-loss-how-can-i-check-what-i-did-wrong)

I feel like it is actually more than one question, but when I tried splitting it up into two seperate questions I didn't have a clue how I should phrase it or link the context together, and still be able to discuss the topic. In this case I find it necessary to discuss it with both topics in mind. Since I'm thinking it doesn't directly into the Q&A model, I would like to ask:

What should be done to split questions up in reasonable way?

---

I realize the question is somewhat subjective but I still think there should be some tips available for people having trouble with these things. Therefore I hope I phrased the question so it is possible to answer broadly.

> **Related:** [How to split 1 big question (and answer) into several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133750/how-to-split-1-big-question-and-answer-into-several-questions)

Comment: upvotes and downvotes but no comments? Anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. Also, Sunday mornings (European time) are slow on MSO, so it could be a while before anything significant happens with your question.